# Unexpected behavior with ANTLR3

Tags: antlr3

I am experiencing an unexpected behavior with ANTLR3. This is my grammar:

```
grammar Onto;

****parser rules****

predicate   
    : VERB
    ;

****lexer rules****

VERB    
    : 'VB'  WS
    ;

PREPOSITION
    : 'TO' WS
    ;

WS
    : (' ' | '\t' | '\r'| '\n')
    ;
```

When I parse the string "VB TO", ANTLR3 exits without flagging an error. This is unexpected because the given string does not match any rule in the grammar.

However when I retry the same after removing the PREPOSITION rule from the grammar, ANTLR3 flags the following error which is the expected result:

```
line 1:3 no viable alternative at character 'T'
line 1:4 no viable alternative at character 'O'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made the classic mistake. Your main rule has no EOF at the end, so your parser currently also matches only a part of your input and sees that as valid. In your case it matches VERB and then expects nothing more. That PREPOSITION matches your "TO" input is part of the behavior as this returns the PREPOSIITON token to the parser. But since the parser is already happy with the VERB input it considers the parse done successfully.

Without the PREPOSITION lexer rule however, the lexer returns an error token as it cannot match that input. Which is what the error above is about.

Comment: Thanks! But, does this mean I have to add EOF at the end of every parser rule?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work anyway (since they are supposed to match only parts of your grammar). EOF is only necessary for the start rule (or any other which is supposed to match the full input to succeed).